# C# Class Contains Reference Of Another Class As Static Field

Tags: c#, .net, oop, console-application

I have two classes in C#. The first class look like this

```
 public class AppConfig
    {
        public static EmailConfig EmailSetting { get; set; }
    }
```

Another class look like this

```
  public class EmailConfig
    {
        public static string SmtpSectionPath = "MailSettings";
    }
```

Now I want o access EmailCOnfig field like this:

```
AppConfig.EmailSetting.SmtpSectionPath
```

But I am unable to get **SmtpSectionPath**.

How to access the desired functionality?

I have just updated my Code to this:

```
 public class AppConfig
    {
        public static EmailConfig EmailSetting { get { return new EmailConfig(); } }
    }

 public class EmailConfig
    {
        public  string SmtpSectionPath = "MailSettings";
    }
```

Is this the right approach?

Comment: `EmailConfig.SmtpSectionPath;`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `EmailConfig.SmtpSectionPath`.

Static fields of `EmailConfig` don't belong to any particular instance of `EmailConfig`. Unlike some languages, C# prohibits treating them as if they were instance fields.

Comment: @HaseebKhan Your change to `EmailConfig` seems like what you want, but I don't understand why you changed `AppConfig`.

Comment: Yes, after removing static keyword from EmailConfig field, I have got my desired outcome but still, I am unable to get the result which is getting value. In my case, I need to get "EmailSetting". if I don't change the AppCOnfig I get error Object Referecne error

Comment: @HaseebKhan You need to set `EmailSetting` only once. Try a [static constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).  Then read [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't.

You're trying to access a static property as if it was an instance property.

If it really must use a static property then you should just use `EmailConfig.SmtpSectionPath`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your string property like this:

```
AppConfig.EmailSetting.SmtpSectionPath
```

You can remove the static from the `SmtpSectionPath` property:

```
public class EmailConfig
{
    public string SmtpSectionPath = "MailSettings";
}
```

Because you declare `EmailConfig` as static in your `AppConfig`. With this, the instance of `EmailConfig` is static in your `AppConfig` and with this, the `SmtpSectionPath` as well. But if you create a new instance of `EmailConfig`, then your `SmtpSectionPath` contains not the "same" value (It has not the same reference)

If you need the `SmtpSectionPath` as **static**, then you should follow the answer of @Tigran.

Comment: I've understood, what you said. But I want to access other config using AppConfig. What is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following:

```
using System;

namespace console
{
    public interface ISmptSectionPathProvider
    {
        string SmtpSectionPath
        {
            get;
        }
    }

    public class AppConfig : ISmptSectionPathProvider
    {
        public string SmtpSectionPath
        {
            get { return Constants.SmtpSectionPath; }
        }
    }

    public class EmailConfig : ISmptSectionPathProvider
    {
        public string SmtpSectionPath
        {
            get { return Constants.SmtpSectionPath; }
        }
    }

    public class Constants
    {
        public static string SmtpSectionPath = "MailSettings";
    }

    class CommandLineApplication
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ISmptSectionPathProvider provider = new AppConfig();
            System.Console.WriteLine(provider.SmtpSectionPath);
            provider = new EmailConfig();
            System.Console.WriteLine(provider.SmtpSectionPath);
        }
    }
}
```

You could also now remove the static class references altogether and just use the constants class. Using `static` for complex Object models usually leads to very bad designs decisions: you are bound to specific classes (polymorphism can not be used to its full extend) and might run into memory leaks.

Comment: I extended my comment. You should not follow your approach to read a value, which is accessible globally. This will lead to the usage of global variables and years of software engineering showed, that this is a bad pattern. My illustrated approach uses polymorphism and a simple way to provide the values. This decouples information from implementation and makes sure, you can scale in the future.